# How do I get Magento 2 data to use in the template?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.4

I am starting in the Magento development world, and I'm creating a new theme.

On my theme, I have a block which displays business contact info, but I don't know how to get the data from the store.
I have to make a custom menu as well, but stop in the same problem: getting category data from the store.

I also wanted to know if there is any place where you can find more references on this data return issue, such as what available methods and classes are available, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to display the custom data ? In a product page or your custom module's separate page ?

If you want to use custom block in sidebar you can follow steps given here
https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/how-to-add-a-static-block-in-a-sidebar-column-magento-2/.

Here are some ref you can use:

1. https://itectec.com/magento/magento-magento-2-get-custom-module-data-in-theme-phtml/
2. https://code.vky.co.in/display-custom-module-collection-data-frontend-magento-2/